# Explanation of a statement in proposition 20 in Royden " Real Analysis."

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, cantor-set

The proposition and its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

1-Why $\emptyset(1) = 1$?

2-why in the second picture "if $k$ is sufficiently large $x_{0}$ lies between 2 consecutive intervals in $O_{k}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are elements of $\mathcal{O}=[0,1]\setminus \mathcal{C}$ that are arbitrarily close to $1$, so $\varphi(1)=1$. For instance, 
   $$1- \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{2}{3^n}\right) = 1- \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \in \mathcal{O} \text{ for all } n \geq 1$$
   since the interval $\left(1-\frac{2}{3^n}, 1-\frac{1}{3^n}\right)$ is removed from $\mathcal{C}$ for every $n \geq 1$.
2. $x_0$ is some positive distance away from both $0$ and $1$, say $\Delta$. Note that two of the intervals removed at the $k$th step are
   $$\left(\frac{1}{3^k}, \frac{2}{3^k}\right) \text{ and } \left(1-\frac{2}{3^k}, 1-\frac{1}{3^k}\right).$$
   For sufficiently large $k$, we have $\frac{2}{3^k}<\Delta$, and so these intervals will lie on opposite sides of $x_0$. So $x_0$ is between some intervals removed at the $k$th stage, and since only finitely many intervals are removed we can selected the rightmost one that is left of $x_0$, and the leftmost one that is right of $x_0$, which will be consecutive.

Comment: Very nice explanation .... thank you!